# How to access a component's variable , outside the component, in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web-component

In React Native, I have a component (C), which handles some functions, inside a screen component (S) .

I need to submit the variables inside C, to firebase. But the submit button and some other variables, belong to S.

How can a function in S, access variables in C ?

or better yet

How can I access a component's variables, from outside the component?

Do I use `export` inside C (for these variables) or is there a more elegant solution ?

Comment: Generally you would pass a callback function via props from parent to child for the child to call and pass data back to the parent. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) Please try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I see your point. I tried looking at React docs, but they use Class components, and I use the Functional Component syntax. That left some gap for me

Comment: React state and component lifecycle *mostly* functions the same between class-based and functional components. If you can update your question to include example code you've tried we can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this. First is to lift your state up to the parent component `S` where you functions that operate on the **said state** reside. This is the most common thing to do in React world. To lift the state up you have three choices:

1. Redux
2. React Context API
3. Traditional data props: Trickle down data as props across the hierachy of components

Second option is to cleverly use [`useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook. This hook allows the parent pass the **ref** that child can use to send data back to parent without any means of callback. For example:

```
function Child(props, ref) {
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    // Expose a function that can be called by parent
    getCount: () => count
  }), [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Count: {count}</label>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}></button>
    </div>
  );
}

Child = forwardRef(Child);


// Use Child inside the parent
function Parent() {

  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    // Get the state of Child after 4 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(ref.current.getCount());
    }, 4000);

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={ref}></Child>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, I strongly advice against this pattern. You should use it strictly for imperative work (animations, focus, etc.) as suggested by the name of hook.

There is a third option as well. I consider it to be most idiomatic in the world of Functional Components. If both `C` and `S` needs access to the same state, extract the state into custom re-usable hook. That hook would be initialized by `S` and it would pass data to `C`. Both `S` and `C` can work and manipulate the data. Note that this is still the variation of first approach of **Lifting the state**; just that instead of purely lifting, you are also **extracting** the state.